How can I extend Assert.That, Nunit?
Using NUnit 4.2, .NET 8
I can output my own custom exception message when it fails by using the message parameter in Assert.That(). This message gets displayed when the assert fails.
However, i'm looking for a way to output some messages even when the assert is a success.
My use-case is that I have a lot of asserts in a single test method. And I'd like to be able to track what is being asserted in each test method from the CI pipeline.
TestContext.Out.WriteLine works to output logs even on success, I thought i'd extend the Assert.That method so that I don't have a bunch of TestContext.Out.WriteLines after every Assert, but I can't seem to get it to work. (C# skill issues)
[Test]
public void Add_Two_Numbers()
{
    int a = 2, b = 3, c = 4, d = 5;

    int resultAB = a + b;
    int resultCD = c + d;

    Assert.Multiple(() =>
    {
        Assert.That(resultAB, Is.EqualTo(5), message: "Somehow it's not 5", assertDescription: $"Checking if {a}+{b} is equal to 5");
        Assert.That(resultCD, Is.EqualTo(9), message: "Somehow it's not 9", assertDescription: $"Checking if {c}+{d} is equal to 9");
    });
}

Questions:

How can I extend the Assert.That with a new parameter.
Is there a way to verify an Assert is a success? Especially if they're Assert.Multiple() scoped since, that doesn't throw exceptions.

Note: Breaking it down to multiple Test methods is not an option for my particular use-case.

Did you consider Assert.Pass ?


You most certainly can extend Assert. This will satisfy your proposed usage:

using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using NUnit.Framework.Constraints;

public class Assert : NUnit.Framework.Assert
{
  public static void That<T>(
    T actual,
    IResolveConstraint expression,
    string message,
    string assertDescription,
    [CallerArgumentExpression(nameof(actual))] string actualExpression = "",
    [CallerArgumentExpression(nameof(expression))] string constraintExpression = "")
  {
#pragma warning disable NUnit2050 // False warning when we specify actualExpression & constraintExpression
    That(actual, expression, message, actualExpression: actualExpression, constraintExpression: constraintExpression);
#pragma warning restore NUnit2050
    TestContext.Out.WriteLine(assertDescription);
  }
}

public class Tester {
  [Test] public void Test1() {
    int a = 0, b = 3, c = 4, d = 5;
    Assert.Multiple(() => {
      Assert.That(a + b, Is.EqualTo(5), message: "Somehow it's not 5", assertDescription: $"Checking if {a}+{b} is equal to 5");
      Assert.That(c + d, Is.EqualTo(9), message: "Somehow it's not 9", assertDescription: $"Checking if {c}+{d} is equal to 9");
    });
  }
}


Checking if the assert was successful is a bit more involved, especially if you want to keep existing behaviour, as some of the required methods are private.

using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using NUnit.Framework.Constraints;

public class Assert : NUnit.Framework.Assert
{
  private static readonly MethodInfo? ReportFailureMethod;
  static Assert() // Static constructor
  {
    // The ReportFailure() method is a private, 
    // so we need to backdoor it via Reflection.
    ReportFailureMethod = typeof(NUnit.Framework.Assert).GetMethod(
      "ReportFailure",
      BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static,
      [typeof(ConstraintResult), typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string)]);
  }

  public static void That<T>(
    T actual,
    IResolveConstraint expression,
    string message,
    string assertDescription,
    [CallerArgumentExpression(nameof(actual))] string actualExpression = "",
    [CallerArgumentExpression(nameof(expression))] string constraintExpression = "")
  {
    // Emulate what the actual Assert.That() does:
    var constraint = expression.Resolve();
    var result = constraint.ApplyTo(actual);
    
    if (result.IsSuccess)
      TestContext.Out.WriteLine($"Success: {assertDescription}");
    else
      ReportFailureMethod?.Invoke(null, [result, message.ToString(), actualExpression, constraintExpression]);
  }
}

Unfortunately the above messes the stack trace logging. But it's still the closest we could get to emulating the original Assert.That() while catching a successful assert.

Sorry for slow response, I'd seen your answer but didn't get the chance to test it out. This is exactly what I was looking for. Just 1 change, I used NUnitString message=default as the parameter instead of string, to extend Assert.That without a custom failure message. Because when you call Assert.That without a message it seems to cause errors if it's a string.

Assert is static class, which cannot be extended with extension methods, so you can't create new method on Assert as you would like.
What you can do however, is to define own method, such as:
public static class AssertExt
{
    public static void ThatAndLog(string logMessage, ...other params)
    {
        TestContext.Out.WriteLine(logMessage); // or use Assert.Pass
        Assert.That(...other params);
    }
}

And then use it in tests:
AssertExt.ThatAndLog("log message", resultAB, Is.EqualTo(5));


Thanks, but this didn't resolve my second question which was to check the result of the assert.
